# using iterator for vectors in a list

Tags: c++

I am trying to use iterator in a list as follows, is this the right way to do it?

I have two vectors v1 and v2 and I am using two iterators it1 and it2. Later, I am using a list which is `list<vector<int>::iterator>` to push_back the iterators it1 and it2. This works, but if any one of the vector is empty, it crashes.

```
int main() {
vector<int> v1 ={1,2,3};
vector<int> v2 ={4,5,6,7};

vector<int>::iterator it1 = v1.begin();
vector<int>::iterator it2 = v2.begin();


list<vector<int>::iterator> l;
l.push_back(it1);
l.push_back(it2);

for(auto a : l){
    vector<int>::iterator it = a;
    while(*it){
        cout<<*it<<endl;
        it++;
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty crazy. Why a vector of iterators, they get invalidated if the vector is mutated? Also you are not capturing the end iterator. That is how you should know you are at the end of the vector, not `*it`. If the list is empty `begin == end` and so you have no iterations and no need to dereference `it`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will fail as you cannot dereference an iterator until you know its valid to dereference. If the vector is empty `begin == end` and end is not a valid thing to dereference, as it's one off the end of the container.

You wont be able to iterate your container without knowing the `end` and you don't capture it, you only capture `begin`. Simply dereferencing the iterator to test for validity is not correct. It could hold any value.

What about an alternative where you capture a pair of iterators for each vector?

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    const vector<int> v1 ={1,2,3};
    const vector<int> v2 ={4,5,6,7};

    list<pair<vector<int>::const_iterator, 
              vector<int>::const_iterator>> L;

    L.push_back(make_pair(begin(v1), end(v1)));
    L.push_back(make_pair(begin(v2), end(v2)));

    for(const auto& a : L){

        for(auto it = a.first; it != a.second; ++it)
        {
            cout << *it << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have the capability to stop as you know the end iterator too.

Answer (score 2):

The crash is coming from trying to dereference `it` in the line `while(*it){`. If a vector `v` is empty, then the iterator `v.begin()` won't point to valid memory, and dereferencing it will cause a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: That is why you always check before you do something with the iterator or any pointer in general. before your while loop just simply add if(*it) { while(*it) cout << *it << endl; it++; } else { return; }

Comment: @OmidCompSCI I dont think that is going to help.`if(*it)` is also dereferencing and will fail.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Don't think that will work, the Segmentation Fault will still occur.

Comment: Of course it fails its doing a dereference. You need the end iterator for it to work at all.

Comment: @PaulRooney The seg fault will not occur if he just used a for loop and the termination condition was it!=it.end(), then you can add the check I have if(*it) { //whatever u need }

Comment: @OmidCompSCI can you show a running example of this? As far as I know iterators don't have an end member function and how could they have any member functions if they are often just pointers.

Comment: @PaulRooney my correction, if he had for(it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) { if(*it) { //do what u want; }. I don't see any problems with this.

Comment: That in itself is fine (although you did put it!=it.end() in your last comment) assuming you have `v` available, however in the final loop of the original code all you have to work with is a single iterator, so no end iterator or reference to the original vector are available. You would have to do something like my answer to have the end iterator available.

Answer (score 0):

```
list<vector<int>::iterator> l;
l.push_back(it1);
```

If suppose `v1` is empty, then `it1` would be `v1::end()` which is one past the last element of vector and is not part of the vector.So later when you do

```
while(*it){
```

you are trying to dereference `v::end()` which is the reason for the crash.To avoid this you should insert into `l` only if the iterators are not pointing to `end`.

```
if(it1!= v1.end())
   l.push_back(it1);
```